# ColdFusion paging and page numbers

Tags: coldfusion

I have a list of user comments stored in a database and I'm displaying 10 per page. On page load I need to dynamically render the appropriate amount of page numbers. At first I thought I would just get the total amount of comments and divide that by 10 to get the # of pages. That however doesn't work correctly. For example:

```
1. 1-10
2. 11-21
3. 22-32
4. 33-43
5. 44-54
6. 55-65
7. 66-76
```

So basically with my original math if I have 70 results I will have 7 pages, but if I have 71 results I get 8 pages, which obviously isn't correct. How can I fix this?

Here's my original code:

```
<cfset commentsNumber = getComments.recordcount / 10>


          <cfloop from="1" to="#commentsNumber#" index="i" >
          <cfoutput>
          #i#
          </cfoutput>
          </cfloop>
```

**Edit:** I can't do math today :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...if I have 71 results I get 8 pages, which obviously isn't correct.

10 results per page w/ 71 results is 8 pages. What's wrong?

Comment: page 1 -> 1 through 10
page 2 -> 11 through 20
..
page 7 -> 61 through 70

Comment: wow I'm losing it, I put 11-21 as 10 items which is actually 11

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure of your record paging in ColdFusion, you could use an open source library like [Pagination.cfc](http://paginationcfc.riaforge.org/). It handles all the math for you and gives you a customizable display.

Answer (score 0):

hey correct you math first.. :) your example is wrong.
If you are showing 10 comments per page then it should be
1. 1-10
2. 11-20
3. 21-30
etc

By the way you can use CFGRID for paging... it's very simple..

Comment: thanks I realized that after Bradley pointed it out. My comments pager is done in AJAX so I just made it from scratch.